# Tkinter: how to embed a text widget onto a canvas widget

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I want to make a text editor in tkinter. First, I created a canvas. Then, I want to embed a text widget inside the canvas like in the image.

[image: click to see image]

My code is below:

```
def run():
    root = tk.Tk()
    global data
    class Struct(object): pass
    data = Struct()
    initData()
    global text
    text = Text(root,width=400,height=500)
    data.root = root
    canvas = Canvas(root,width=1200,height=600)
    canvas.pack()
    text.pack()
    drawBackground(canvas)
    root.mainloop()

run()
```

How should I write the pack statement for text instead of `text.pack()`?

Thank you!

Comment: you have to use `canvas.create_window(text)` instead of `text.pack()`. Find information how to create scrolled frame.

Comment: why do you use `Canvas`? you can put `Text` directly on root and it will work with `Scrollerbars` - other widgets (like `Frame`) need `Canvas` to work with `Scrollbars`. effbot.org: [Tkinter Scrollbar Patterns](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm)

Comment: BTW: if you want `Text` on `Canvas` then `Text` should use `Canvas` as parent - `Text(canvas)`

Comment: You need to first create a `Canvas` `window` object to put in it. [Here's](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/create_window.html) a little documentation.

Comment: Before asking, your first step should be to read through some documentation and then search for existing answers. What you're asking can be answered with just a little bit of research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `canvas.create_window()` instead of `text.pack()`.
And `Text` should use `canvas` as parent: `Text(canvas)`

BTW: `width` and `height` in `Text` is in `chars`, not in `pixels`.
`Text` will use different size in pixels for different font.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class Struct(object):
    pass

# --- functions ---

def run():
    # all `global` always at the top of function
    # to make it more readable
    global data
    global text

    data = Struct()
    #initData(data)

    root = tk.Tk()

    data.root = root

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=1200, height=600)
    canvas.pack()
    #drawBackground(canvas)

    # Text needs `canvas` as parent.
    # `width` and `height` is in `chars`, not in `pixels`.
    # `Text` will use different size in pixels for different font.

    text = tk.Text(canvas, width=120, height=40)
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=text, anchor='nw')

    text.insert('end', 'Hello World')

    root.mainloop()

# --- main ---

run()
```

---

**BTW:** if you want image in background then you can use `Label` with image
and then you can put `Text` inside `Label` using `Label` as parent.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def run():
    # all `global` always at the top of function
    # to make it more readable
    global text

    root = tk.Tk()

    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='image.jpg')

    label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    label.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    label.image = image # keep reference - see Note on effbot.org 

    # Text needs `label` as parent
    # `padx`, `pady` create external margin so you can see background

    text = tk.Text(label)
    text.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=100, pady=100)

    text.insert('end', 'Hello World')    

    root.mainloop()

# --- main ---

run()
```

BTW: see **Note** about "garbage collecting" and keeping reference: [Photoimage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for and more! Thank you so much for helping out!